# Can anyone help a newbie write the custom css code? (style inherited border on widget)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

### I am learning as i go for a new website i am working on, never done custom css before. *(am noob, please be nice)*

Using Theme bemart from themeforest, Kingcomposer Pro, and wordpress. 
(current plugin for widget css is zigwidgetclass)

[www.aboutautomation.com.au](http://www.aboutautomation.com.au)  (for inspect element)

---

I am trying to remove the border on just ONE widget on the side bar (custom_html-9) it is currently being inherited from the theme customisation and when edited will change all borders, which is undesirable. i am wanting to either make this a css class for this widget either making it #ffffff

but i cant manage to get it going, the only thing i have managed is to make it disappear completely with

```
.hide {
border: #ffffff; }
```

i am not even sure how that happened?!

does have a custom css on it already hide_on_mobile

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
.hide_on_mobile {
display: none !important;}
}
```

Comment: Ask question properly with code formatted and with required details

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried to solve it and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
#custom_html-9 .custom-html-widget {
    border: transparent;
}
```

The contents shift if you removed the border completely (as they take up space) so set the border to transparent so you cannot see it but continues to take up space.

You could also use any combo of CSS classes on the parent `aside` elements and the inner `div`. Some other options include:

```
.sidebar .widget_text .textwidget
.sidebar .widget_text .custom-html-widget
.sidebar .widget_custom_html .textwidget
.sidebar .widget_custom_html .custom-html-widget
```

The current border is being applied with multiple CSS selectors and it looks like you'll need at least 3 classes or an ID in your selector in order to override the original.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, works perfectly - that's what i suspected that i had to keep the border there. so i have tried to make it the same color as the background. (why did my original hide class not work with changing the color to white?)

Comment: The specificity of your selector. `.hide` has a specificity of `0 0 1 0` which is not high enough to override the existing selectors. There were multiple selectors that had a higher specificity; `.widget_text .textwidget` with a specificity of `0 0 2 0` and `.sidebar > .widget > div` with a specificity of `0 0 2 1`. In order to override existing styles your selector has to at least match the existing style's specificity value and come after the selector. Specificity is a matrix of values and importance moves from left to right.